# Creating gallery in html DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want create in html tags which will create gallery,I have 7 images and I want this images will display one time.this means this code must output 3 rows 7 images.

```
    var img=["sea.jpg","monkey.jpg","birtday.jpg","picture.jpg","nintendo.png","square.png","chrome.png"];


function gallery(galleryWidth,columnCount,gutter,divCount){
    var n=0;
    document.write('<div class="gallery"style="width:'+galleryWidth+'px">');    

            while(n<img.length%columnCount){
            document.write('<div class="row">');
            for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
                document.write('<div class="galItem"style="width:'+(galleryWidth/columnCount-2*gutter)+'px;margin:'+gutter+'px"> <img src="img/'+img[i]+'"/></div>');
            img.shift();
        }

            document.write('</div>');
            document.write('<div class="clear"></div>');

            n++;
    }

    document.write("</div>");   

    }

gallery(240,3,5,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seem like this.

```js
var img = ["sea.jpg", "monkey.jpg", "birtday.jpg", "picture.jpg", "nintendo.png", "square.png", "chrome.png"];
    
    
        function gallery(galleryWidth, columnCount, gutter) {
            document.write('<div class="gallery"  style="width:' + galleryWidth + 'px">');
    
            for (var j = 0; j < img.length; j++) {
                var startNewLine = j && !(j % columnCount);
                if (startNewLine) {
                    document.write('<div class="row">');
                }
    
                document.write('<div class="galItem" style="width:' + (galleryWidth / columnCount - 2 * gutter) + 'px;margin:' + gutter + 'px"> <img  alt="' + img[j] + '"/></div>');
                if (startNewLine) {
                    document.write('</div>');
                    document.write('<div class="clear"></div>');
                }
            }
    
            document.write("</div>");
        }
        gallery(240, 3, 5, 7);
```

```css
.row {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.clear {
    height: 0;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:30px;
}

.galItem {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, avoid document.write. There are far more reliable ways of doing this. Second, do/while and your for loop seem to be getting tangled. This may be what you're trying to do.

```js
   var img = ["sea.jpg",
     "monkey.jpg",
     "birtday.jpg",
     "picture.jpg",
     "nintendo.png",
     "square.png",
     "chrome.png"
   ];


   function gallery(galleryWidth, columnCount, gutter, divCount) {
     this.width = galleryWidth;
     this.cols = columnCount;
     this.gutter = gutter;
     this.divs = divCount;
     var myRow, myDiv, myImg, myClearDiv;
     var n = 0;
     var myGallery = document.createElement('div');

     myGallery.classList.add('gallery');
     myGallery.style.width = this.width + "px";

     myRow = document.createElement('div');
     myRow.classList.add('row');

     for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
       if (n >= this.cols) {
         myGallery.appendChild(myRow);
         myClearDiv = document.createElement("div");
         myClearDiv.classList.add("clear");
         myGallery.appendChild(myClearDiv);


         myRow = document.createElement('div');
         myRow.classList.add('row');
         n = 0;
       }
       myDiv = document.createElement('div');
       myDiv.classList.add('galItem');
       myDiv.style.width = this.width / this.cols - 2 * this.gutter + 'px';
       myDiv.style.margin = this.gutter + 'px';

       // Create the image element, and append it...
       myImg = document.createElement('img');
       myImg.src = '"img/' + img[i] + '"';
       myDiv.appendChild(myImg);

       // then, append the div to the row.
       myRow.appendChild(myDiv);

       n++;
     }

     myGallery.appendChild(myRow);
     myClearDiv = document.createElement("div");
     myClearDiv.classList.add("clear");
     myGallery.appendChild(myClearDiv);


     myRow = document.createElement('div');
     myRow.classList.add('row');

     var container = document.getElementById("container");
     container.appendChild(myGallery);
   }

   gallery(600, 3, 5, 4);
```

```css
.galItem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```